# Problems with Window Function when trying to get a Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL and I'm trying to add a new column to my table which is economic growth or basically the % change in rgdpe from year to year. Here is my code:

```
Select country, 
              year, 
              rgdpe, 
             (lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as col_help,
             (case
                   when 
                       cast(col_help as Decimal(10,2)) is NULL 
                   then 
                        "Na"
                    when
                         cast(rgdpe as Decimal(10,2)) = 0 or cast(col_help as Decimal(10,2)) = 0
                    then 
                         cast(0 as Decimal(10,2))
                    else
                         round((((cast(rgdpe as Decimal(10,2))  - cast(col_help as Decimal(10,2)))*100)/(cast(col_help as Decimal(10,2)))), 3)
             end) as Economic_Growth
from pwt100 
order by country, year;
```

This is my output:

| country | year | rgdpe | col_help | economic_growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Antigua | 1970 | 306.72 | 0 | Na |
| Antigua | 1971 | 329.42 | 306.72 | Na |
| Antigua | 1972 | 353.69 | 329.42 | Na |

This is what I want:

| country | year | rgdpe | col_help | economic_growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Antigua | 1970 | 306.72 | 0 | Na |
| Antigua | 1971 | 329.42 | 306.72 | 7.40 |
| Antigua | 1972 | 353.69 | 329.42 | 7.42 |

Clearly it seems that the value of col_help are Null even though they aren't. How do I change this? Thanks in advance!

Update: For those curious this is what worked

```
Select country, 
          year, 
          rgdpe, 
         coalesce(lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as previous_amount,
         coalesce(100.0*(((cast(rgdpe as Decimal(10,2)))-(lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)))/(lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year))), 0) as Economic_Growth
From pwt100
order by country, year;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the alias `col_help` in the same `select` statement in which you defined it. You could try using a sub-query, or you could try repeating the `col_help` expression as shown in the code below:

```
Select country, 
              year, 
              rgdpe, 
             (lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as col_help,
             (case
                   when 
                   cast((lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as Decimal(10,2)) is NULL 
                   then 
                   "Na"
                   when
                   cast(rgdpe as Decimal(10,2)) = 0 or 
                   cast((lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as Decimal(10,2)) = 0
                   then 
                   cast(0 as Decimal(10,2))
                   else
                   round((((cast(rgdpe as Decimal(10,2)) - cast((lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as Decimal(10,2)))*100)
                   /(cast((lag(rgdpe) over(Partition by country Order by year)) as Decimal(10,2)))), 3)end) as Economic_Growth
from pwt100 
order by country, year;
```

Comment: this doesn't work but i will go ahead and try using a sub-query

Comment: It looks like `col_help` was in more places than I first spotted, I have updated the code.